# What happens to a lock on a boost interprocess mutex if a process forks while the lock is acquired?

Tags: c++, boost, concurrency, boost-interprocess

Let's say we have a process with two threads.  One thread does some work on some shared resource and periodically takes out a scoped lock on a boost::interprocess::mutex.   The other thread causes a fork/exec, at some random time.

Thread 1

```
void takeLockDoWork() {
    using namespace boost::interprocess;
    managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, "xxx");
    interprocess_sharable_mutex *mutex = segment.find<interprocess_sharable_mutex>("mymutex").first;
    scoped_lock<interprocess_sharable_mutex> lock(*mutex);
    // access or do work on a shared resource here
    //lock automatically unlocks when scope is left.
}
```

Let's say Thread 2 forks right after the scoped_lock is taken out.  Presumably the child process has the same lock state as the parent.

What happens?   Will there now be a race condition with the parent process?

Comment: A more interesting question is what will happen if the fork happened while the shared resource was in the middle of being written to. Even if the system is smart enough to make one of the threads wait to acquire the mutex again, when that thread does acquire the mutex it may have a different view of the shared resource than when it started (because the other thread may have finished whatever task it was in the middle of when it forked). I would strongly suggest synchronizing forking with a read/write lock; all threads can hold a read lock to prevent a fork and a write lock is acquired to fork.

Comment: I'd strongly advise against forking when there's more than one thread. And opening the shmem in each child process if required. Or isolate the sharing process from the forking process from the start. Anything that doesn't rely on platform-dependent/unspecified behaviours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't fork from a thread that is holding an `interprocess_sharable_mutex` or access memory that was being protected by a mutex, you're okay.

The mutex exists in shared memory, meaning that even though you forked, the mutex state wasn't duplicated; it exists in one place, accessible by both processes.

Because forking only maintains the forking thread in the child, only the other thread in the parent thinks it has ownership of the mutex, so there's no problem. Even if you tried to acquire the mutex after forking, you would still be okay; it would just block until the parent releases it.